# Implication of not being continuous at a point

Tags: general-topology

$f\colon X\to Y$ is a function between topological spaces and it is not continuous at $x$. Why does this imply there is an open set $V\subseteq Y$ with $f(x)\in V$ and for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $f(U)\setminus V \neq \emptyset$? (Found in the proof of Prop 2.4 in Appendix A, Course in Functional Analysis by Conway)

My understanding is that since $f$ is not continuous at $x$, there must be some open $V$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, but it is not open. So this means $f^{-1}(V)\neq U$ for any open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. However, why can't it be the case that $U \subset f^{-1}(V)$? Then $f^{-1}(V)\neq U$ but $f(U)\setminus V = \emptyset$.

Comment: It is incorrect that for a point where $f$ is not continuous, there always exists some $V\subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is a non-open neighborhood. Think about $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=1$ for every $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then, for any neighborhood $V\ni 0$, $f^{-1}(V)=\{0\}$ or $f^{-1}(V)=\Bbb R$, depending on whether or not $1\in V$. Neither $\{0\}$ nor $\Bbb R$ is a non-open neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Danu Although, is $\{0\}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, $\{0\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, since $\Bbb R$ is $T_1$ (even Hausdorff, and even more than that!).

Comment: Closed does not imply not open, but I think you're right that $\{0\}$ is closed and not open. But then in your example, $\{0\}$ is a non-open neighbourhood of 0, is that correct?

Comment: Since $\Bbb R$ is connected, closed does imply not open for proper subsets. And no, the entire point I was making is that that assertion fails! You should look up the definition of a neighborhood.

Comment: So your last sentence is supposed to be a contradiction? I think I understand your example, just the last statement was a bit confusing for me. In any case, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Danu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/96250/danu)! I needed to review the definition of continuity at a point. $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if for every open neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that whenever $x\in U$, $f(x)\in V$. In other words, $f(U)\subseteq V$.

So the negation of the statement would be: if $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, then there exists $V$ open and containing $f(x_0)$ such that for all $U$ open and containing $x_0$, $f(U)\supset V$, or $f(U)\setminus V\neq \emptyset$.